# Windows 7 can recognize only one Nexus 7 tablet. It can't see a new one

Tags: android, eclipse

I hope someone can help me.I could connect my windows 7 machine and Eclipse successfully to my nexus 7. I lost my tablet and I bought the new one but now my windows machine can't even recognize it as external device neither my Eclipse works with it anymore. Does windows 7 keeps USB ID somewhere? Should I re install something?I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this development related?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have USB Debugging enabled.

Open up Device Manager. Do you see a tab for ADB Devices? Do you see your N7 anywhere on the list?

If not, on your tablet, go in and change the PC Connection mode to whichever one it is not on. And then try again.

I have had problems with my N7 as well where it will only connect when set to a certain connection type.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes USB debugging is enabled. I can see  SAMSUNG Android phone-->Android Composite ADB interface  when I connect it to my machine.. How can I change the connectivity type on Nexus 7? It says "Connected as Media device" .

Comment: I can see two options for connectivity MTP and PTP( camera) .If I select PTP then my windows machine can recognize it but with MTP it can't.

Comment: My windows machine can't even see it as mass storage device.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if Eclipse is not installed on the computer, the computer is able to see multiple Nexus 7 tablets as MTP devices.  However, for computers that have Eclipse installed on them they can only see the first Nexus 7 tablet connected to them as an MTP device.  All other tablets connected to the computer are seen as an unspecified device.  It seems like Eclipse is storing a unique identifier from the first tablet associated with it.  The only way I can get apps built in Eclipse onto my other Nexus 7 tablets is to change the usb connection to PTP (not MTP) and then my windows 7 computer sees my tablet as a camera and I can move the .apk file over to the tablet.  Is this how it's suppose to work?